# Map one typename to another in a function template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, complex-numbers

I am writing function templates to work with `float`, `double`, `std::complex<float>`, and `std::complex<double>` types.

I often need to declare a type that corresponds to "same precision but purely real". So both `float` and `std::complex<float>` would map to `float`, etc.

I've been doing this with an overload like:

```
template <typename numeric_t, typename real_t>
numeric_t foo(numeric_t x) {
    real_t y = abs(x);
    return x/y;
}

template <typename T> // Used when x is real
T bar(T x) { return foo<T,T>(x); }

template <typename T> // Overload takes precedence when x is complex
complex<T> bar(complex<T> x) { return foo<complex<T>,T>(x); }
```

but that seems pretty cumbersome, especially since I need to define these for each such function I write. Is there a better way to do this?

---

In this example, I can do:

```
template <typename numeric_t>
numeric_t bar(numeric_t x) {
    auto y = abs(x);
    return x/y;
}
```

because `abs()` has been appropriately overloaded. And that's great! That's exactly what I'm looking for. But what if I'm not calling `abs`? Or if `real_t` is the return type?

Comment: `auto`, overloads, traits can help.

Comment: @KQS - I've improved my answer (following a suggestion from aschepler)

Comment: @max66 Thanks! I'm glad you kept your previous answer, though---seeing multiple examples of how to use type traits was very helpful for me.

Comment: @KQS - sorry: I've confused `real_t` with "return type" so my answer is wrong regarding the return type (and the difference C++11/C++14); some minutes and I'll correct it.

Comment: @max66 That's fine; I noticed that too but I understood what you meant. I think your comment would be a sufficient disclaimer for future readers.

Comment: @KQS - I've corrected the answer (I hope so); sorry again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define a simple type traits that detect the right return type, like the following `realType`

```
template <typename T>
struct realType
 { using type = T; };

template <typename T>
struct realType<std::complex<T>>
 { using type = T; };
```

the `bar()` function can be written as

```
template <typename T>
T bar (T const & x)
 { return foo<T, typename realType<T>::type>(x); }
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <complex>

template <typename T>
struct realType
 { using type = T; };

template <typename T>
struct realType<std::complex<T>>
 { using type = T; };

template <typename numeric_t, typename real_t>
numeric_t foo(numeric_t x)
 {
   real_t y = abs(x);
   return x/y;
 }

template <typename T>
T bar (T const & x)
 { return foo<T, typename realType<T>::type>(x); }

int main ()
 {
   using type1 = decltype(bar<float>(1.0f));
   using type2 = decltype(bar<std::complex<double>>(1.0));

   static_assert(std::is_same<type1, float>{}, "!");
   static_assert(std::is_same<type2, std::complex<double>>{}, "!");
 }
```

Off topic suggestion.

Your `foo()` function has two template types but only the first one (`numeric_t`) can be deduced from the input parameter (`x`). So you are forced to explicit both of they.

If you invert the order of the template types

```
template <typename real_t, typename numeric_t>
numeric_t foo(numeric_t x)
 {
   real_t y = abs(x);
   return x/y;
 }
```

you can call `foo()` explicating only the first and letting the compiler to deduce the second one; so `bar()` can be written as

```
template <typename T>
T bar (T const & x)
 { return foo<typename realType<T>::type>(x); }
```

**-- EDIT --**

As suggested by aschepler (thanks!) you can deduce the `real_t` type in `foo()` from `numeric_t`; so, without switching the two template types, you can write `foo()` as follows

```
template <typename numeric_t,
          typename real_t = typename realType<numeric_t>::type>
numeric_t foo(numeric_t x)
 {
   real_t y = abs(x);
   return x/y;
 }
```

and `bar()` simply become

```
template <typename T>
T bar (T const & x)
 { return foo(x); }
```

Comment: Or you could just give `foo` the one template parameter `numeric_t` in the first place and use `typename retType<numeric_t>::type` whereever a real type is wanted.

Comment: Off-topic question: why `std::is_same<a,b>{}` instead of `std::is_same<a,b>::value` (in the `static_assert` in `main()`)?

Comment: @KQS - because it's a little shorter; `::value` it's also OK; `std::is_same<a, b>{}` works because there it's a `bool()` member (so a converter to `bool`), in `std::is_same`, that return the value of `value`.

Comment: @KQS - starting from C++14 you can also use `std::is_same<a, b>{}()` because (from C++14) it's available a `bool operator()` that return (again) the value of `value`